# Windows 10 activation error (0xC004F211)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, windows-activation

I have Windows 10 installed in a virtual machine on VirtualBox.

Recently, I switched out the hard drive in that host system, for an SSD, and migrated the VM back onto that machine. I.e. all that has changed in the hardware setup, is the SSD, however this shouldn't be transparent to the guest OS anyway.

Now, after re-starting that VM, I'm getting a Windows 10 activation error:

> Windows reported that the hardware of your device has changed. Error code: 0xC004F211

It further tells me, that the product key I've entered, cannot be used on the copy of Windows.

This VM was originally a Win7 VM, and I've then upgraded to Win10, which went fine. This is the first time I've had a problem like that.

When going through *Settings > Activation > Troubleshoot* It lingers around a little, and finally ends with:

> **Troubleshooting has completed**
>
> We weren't able to activate Windows on this device.

When I click on "I recently changed hardware in this Computer" it just shows me an error message:

> Unable to activate Windows
>
> We can't find any devices linked to your Microsoft account that can be used to reactivate the device that you're using at the moment. Make sure that you're signed in with the same Microsoft account that you linked to the Windows 10 digital license on this device or try again later.

When I click on "other devices linked to this account" it doesn't show anything, as there are none.

This is the only way I use Windows, it's this one VM, too.

The product key isn't an OEM key. I've been given that key while upgrading from Windows 7. And as I said, it's a VM, not any particular hardware.

I'm kind of scared a little that things will lock up. I need this VM for work, but at the same time, I don't see why I should get another Windows 10 license, when move the VM onto a different hypervisor.

I'm also confused in what to make of the *"try again later"* message.

How do I get rid of the "needs activation" error, and how do I re-activate my Windows 10 on a VM?

Comment: After restarting the VM, the error message went away for a couple hours, but now it's back. I was just about to write an answer, that the problem seemingly has "solved itself", but nope, it just took some time.

Comment: Are you 100% the Windows 7 key is a Retail key? The error you have received indicates it’s something other than a Retail key. You activate Windows on a VM identically to that of a physical machine. If the key is eligible to be activated within the VM, it’s simply activated, once the installation is finished.

Comment: @Ramhound It is not a retail code, I got it from the University I work at. I installed the OS on a VM, because that's how I use Windows exclusively, I'm just amazed why it's now throwing an error, as the version isn't installed on two VMs or two machines, or something. In fact the VM was *migrated*, it's not a fresh install, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a VLK installation, which cannot be activated, with being able to communicate with the appropriate KMS.

Comment: @Ramhound not sure what a VLK or a KMS is, but it worked like that before, etc. the VM is even on the same physical machine and has the same permissions as before. I.e. it is not firewalled against something, etc.

Comment: You have to configure a machine to connect to a KMS. It just doesn’t happen automatically. If it’s not a Retail or OEM key then it has to be a VLK.  VLK has rules of it can be activated, but the lack of details, makes it difficult to give you a detailed explanation of your inability to activate your installation

Comment: @Ramhound tbh, I don't know the details myself. Back when I installed the VM for the first time, I just downloaded the image, installed it as normal in the VM, and it just worked. This is the first time for me, that I'm encountering issues like that.